# Shell script works fine manually but won't work in cron

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I've tried to lookup various solutions to this but none seem to work.

I can run:

```
 /home/ubuntu/success.sh
```

and it runs fine.

but when i try to do this in my cron script....nothing is outputted:

```
  * * * * * /home/ubuntu/success.sh >> tmp/cron_output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need a fullpath for the output file?

```
  * * * * * /home/ubuntu/success.sh >> /tmp/cron_output
```